# how can I match legend colors with plot colors?

Tags: python, legend, scatter-plot

I'm working with a pretty simple example. I create three scatter plots on the same set of axes, and each data set I plot has a different associated colormap. However, the legend does not look as I'd want it to; why is this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=500, n_features=2, cluster_std=1.0, centers=[(0,0), (3,3)])

plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=y, s=50, cmap='rainbow');


clf_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_depth=1)
clf_tree = clf_tree.fit(X, y)
y_pred = clf_tree.predict(X)

clf_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', min_samples_leaf = 3)
clf_tree = clf_tree.fit(X, y)
y_pred = clf_tree.predict(X)

clf_tree = DecisionTreeClassifier(criterion='entropy', max_leaf_nodes = 3)
clf_tree = clf_tree.fit(X, y)
y_pred = clf_tree.predict(X)



#shap.decision_plot(expected_value, sh, features_display, link='logit', highlight=misclassified)

for i in range(len(y)):
    if y[i] != y_pred[i]:
        plt.scatter(X[i, 0], X[i, 1], c=y[i], s=50, cmap='Dark2')
plt.legend(("0","1","miss"))
```

[image]

Comment: You want to do it following the [code here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html). Key element is to label each series as you plot it, then show the legend. When you call `legend()` at the end, you shouldn't pass any arguments and it will pull them automatically from the plotted data, so long as you label that data as you plot it.

Answer (score 0):

You can set them manually like this:

```
plt.legend(("0","1","miss"))
ax = plt.gca()
leg = ax.get_legend()
leg.legendHandles[0].set_color('purple')
leg.legendHandles[1].set_color('red')
leg.legendHandles[2].set_color('green')
plt.show()
```